# Is there a port of DirectFB?

Tags: software-compilation

The website states that progress has been made ["using Raspberry PI or other Broadcom hardware"](http://directfb.org/index.php?path=Main/News&entry=2012-04-14-0.dok).

I've looked at their graphics support and BCM2835 wasn't there. If it has been ported then what are the required libraries and tools to compile it for the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Have you tried compiling it yourself with your standard tools? Perhaps give it a go, if there are any errors then we might be able to provide more help.

Comment: [Have you read this?](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=11772)

Comment: Debian for one seems to have directfb on armel. Maybe your question is actually about something else (like whether a specific acceleration is available)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=16020&p=170011) clearly indicates somebody has gotten it working. A download is attached there (v1.6) the guys' working version.

[This thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=11772) also indicates that it sort of works, including with v1.7 and limited EGL support.

To make a long story short, it looks like the pieces to make this happen are floating around out there, but I don't see them all in one place or debugged to the point where there is are install packages that would just work in any of the major RPI distros.